YUV: Change the Chroma Subsampling and Bit Depth Without Losing Quality
Let's say I have a short video with YUV 4:4:4 and 10bit depth, and I convert it to a FFV1 with YUV 4:2:0 and 8bit depth. Is the FFV1 lossless? Will the colors be the same?
If so, how do I convert videos while changing the chroma subsampling and bit depth without losing quality and get the right colors?

What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this?
